# adding triple dot in userform if text is too long in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

adding triple dot in userform label description if text is too long in vba excel

For example I am having 5 labels in userform as id, name, phone no, address and email id, if the text size of each cell of the student details exceed 10 letters then it need to show 3 dots at the last.
    name:    abcdefghij...
    adress:  abc street, def colony...

Help me to create code in vba userform excel

Answer (score 1):

A simple function should do, unless you want to return full words.

```
Public Function TrimText(Value As String)
    TrimText = IIf(Len(Value) > 10, Left(Value, 10) & "...", Value)
End Function
```

To call it:

```
TrimText("abcdefghijklmnopq")
'abcdefghij...
```

Comment: how can i use this function for each cell of each row? consider I am having  set of 6 rows and 5 columns. how will i call this function?

Comment: Loop through each cell and pass the cell value to the function. `c.Value =  TrimText(c.Value)`